# Switching from ChromeBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject to ChromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register does not let me handle function calls

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

In an older CEF version (73.1.13), I register an object with (C#)

```
ChromeBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("extInterop", new CommandObject(this),
  new BindingOptions() {CamelCaseJavascriptNames = false});
```

The webpage I have loaded uses javascript to find the extInterop object and calls a function inside it.
It will be received in the CommandObject class (C#).

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace foo
{
    public class CommandObject
    {
        public void executeCommand(string command, object value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(command + " " + value.ToString());
        }));
    }
}
```

and the web page uses the javascript

```
window.extInterop.executeCommand("thecommand", 0);
```

This works fine, the command is received as I expect in the CommandObject.

However, when I have upgraded CEF to a newer version (85.3.13), I get a System.NotImplementedException and the message containing a link (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2990) where instructions on how to replace the call can be found. I tried to replace it with

```
ChromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("extInterop",
   new CommandObject(this), isAsync: true, options: BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
```

But messages sent as before from the javascript end are never delivered in the C# end.

Why not?

Comment: In version 73 the RegisterAsyncJsObject method simply calls Register see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/73/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L77 you've changed your binding options, have you tested using the same options?

Comment: I tested `ChromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("extInterop", new CommandObject(this), isAsync: true, options: new BindingOptions());`, but the event handler does not receive any event.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the DevTools console? Have you set CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled?

Comment: Yes, I have CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true and the devtools console does not puke at me.

Comment: I try this at version 86.0.24 now (the latest).

Comment: Can you provide an example that reproduces the problem? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Test/JavascriptBinding/IntegrationTestFacts.cs#L80 is the current test that runs all the qunit tests. If you can add a failing test case then I can see what's going on.

Comment: I need to find a fiddle that can run a windows forms application then. I thought dotnetfiddle maybe was such a page, but I am not sure.

Comment: Can you fork https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and push your changes to GitHub please. Squash your changes into a single commit a single commit please. That'll make reviewing easier,  thanks.

Comment: Try  ChromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true; before calling Register.

Comment: I have tried both `CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;` and `ChromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true;`.

Comment: Thanks for checking, if you can provide an example I'll have a look.